# Java API that can analyze HTTP requests for malicious inputs?

Tags: java

my idea is to create a proxy application firewall that will analyze and filter out HTTP requests from the client accessing a web application, here's a scenario let say a web application that will ask a user for log in details, the proxy application firewall should then be able to analyze the HTTP request from the user for any invalid characters like quotes '',""_-@ and so on.

Answer (score 2):

OWASP [AppSensor](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_AppSensor_Project) and [Shiro security](http://shiro.apache.org/) projects may be the APIs you are looking for.